# Use of parenthesis on LHS when assigning multiple columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Given data

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
   x  y
1: 1  6
2: 2  7
3: 3  8
4: 4  9
5: 5 10
```

Lets say I want two new columns with the mean of `x` and `y`. I can easily do this by providing a character vector of column names on left hand side (LHS) of `:=`:

```
dt[, c("mean_x", "mean_y") := lapply(.SD, mean)]
```

But if I assign the column names to a vector beforehand, and use the *name* of the vector as LHS, I get an error:

```
new_names = c("mean_x", "mean_y")
dt[, new_names := lapply(.SD, mean)]
# Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(new_names , lapply(.SD, mean))) : 
#   Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'cols'.
# If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

However, if I put parenthesis around the name of the vector it works fine

```
dt[, (new_names) := lapply(.SD, mean)]
   x  y mean_x mean_y
1: 1  6      3      8
2: 2  7      3      8
3: 3  8      3      8
4: 4  9      3      8
5: 5 10      3      8
```

What does the parenthesis tell `data.table` internally so that it treats `new_names` as new columns and not something else?

Comment: Another example where parenthesis matters: `data.table(x=c(TRUE, FALSE), y=1:2)[(x)]`

Comment: See `?"("`.  "**Value**: For `(`, the result of evaluating the argument", i.e. the argument _evaluates_ to two column names `c("mean_x", "mean_y")`. _Without_ the parens, `data.table`  thinks that you provide _one_ column name, `new_names`, to which data.table attempts to assign two new columns, hence the error. See also the examples in `:=`:  "_using forced evaluation_"

Comment: ...and in **Details**: "`DT[i, (colvector) := val]`; The parens are enough to stop the LHS being a symbol;

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. You have to be able to separate a new column name `new_names` from the vector `new_names`. Would this be equivalent to `dt[, eval(new_names) := ...]`, since you have to evaluate the vector of names before doing the operation?

Comment: Also the [Reference semantics vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html): **2 e) Multiple columns and `:=`**: Note that since we allow assignment by reference without quoting column names when there is only one column as explained in Section 2c, we can not do `out_cols := lapply(.SD, max)`. That would result in adding one new column named `out_col`. Instead we should do either `c(out_cols)` or simply `(out_cols)`. Wrapping the variable name with `(` is enough to differentiate between the two cases.

Comment: Thank you @Henrik. I see that I need to read the vignette more carefully.